# How to solve this system of equations:

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, cauchy-riemann-equations

The original question is: Where is the function below differentiable:

$$\begin{cases}
f(z) = e^{x^2-y^2}*[\cos(2xy) - i\sin(2xy)]
\end{cases}$$

Using Cauchy-Riemann:

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\delta(u)}{\delta(x)} = 2xe^{x^2-y^2}cos(2xy) - 2ye^{x^2-y^2}sin(2xy),\\
\frac{\delta(u)}{\delta(x)} = 2xe^{x^2-y^2}cos(2xy) - 2ye^{x^2-y^2}sin(2xy)
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\delta(v)}{\delta(x)} = -2xe^{x^2-y^2}sin(2xy) - 2ye^{x^2-y^2}cos(2xy),\\
\frac{\delta(u)}{\delta(y)} = -2ye^{x^2-y^2}cos(2xy) - 2xe^{x^2-y^2}sin(2xy)
\end{cases}$$

The above simplifies to this system of equations that I have no idea how to solve.

$$\begin{cases}
x\cos(2xy)-y\sin(2xy) = 0,\\
x\sin(2xy) + y\cos(2xy) = 0
\end{cases}$$

All the online equation calculator don't want to solve this. I can see there is an obvious root x=0, y=0.

How to solve this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that,

$$
y\sin(2xy)=x\cos(2xy)$$
$$x\sin(2xy)=- y\cos(2xy)
$$

which leads to

$$x^2 = -y^2,\>\>\>\>\tan^2(2xy)=-1$$

Only $x^2 = -y^2$ gives the valid solutions $x=y=0$.

Comment: Thanks, this is so obvious... I was expanding sin(2xy) and cos(2xy) and that went nowhere....

Comment: @JeffNguyen - you're welcome